# Can't access variable in async function

Tags: python, variables, asynchronous

```
class Connect():
    global data_price
    async def main():
       
        client = await AsyncClient.create()
        bm = BinanceSocketManager(client)
        # start any sockets here, i.e a trade socket
        ts = bm.trade_socket('BTCUSDT')
        # then start receiving messages
        async with ts as tscm:
                res = await tscm.recv()
                data_price = res['p']
                print(data_price)
                data_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                data_time = datetime.datetime.now()
                c.execute('''INSERT INTO data VALUES(?,?)''', (data_time, data_price))
                connect_db.commit()
                c.execute('''SELECT * FROM data''')
                data_display = c.fetchall()
                print(data_price)
                Get2(data_price)
                
                
        await client.close_connection()

    if __name__ == "__main__":
        loop = asyncio.get_event_loop()
        loop.run_until_complete(main())
      
    def Get2(data_price):
        print(data_price)
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Rhyan\Desktop\Py project\crytpo.py", line 30, in <module>
    class Connect():
  File "C:\Users\Rhyan\Desktop\Py project\crytpo.py", line 57, in Connect
    loop.run_until_complete(main())
  File "C:\Program Files\WindowsApps\PythonSoftwareFoundation.Python.3.9_3.9.3568.0_x64__qbz5n2kfra8p0\lib\asyncio\base_events.py", line 647, in run_until_complete
    return future.result()
  File "C:\Users\Rhyan\Desktop\Py project\crytpo.py", line 50, in main
    Get2(data_price)
NameError: name 'Get2' is not defined
```

I don't' understand why i can't pass the variable data_price out of the function? even if i'm not passing it out of the function i can't use the variable, it always says it's undefined

Comment: Show the full traceback of the error as properly formatted text in the question.

Comment: You have to pass `self` to methods, then call `self.Get2(...)`.

Comment: Your code makes  little sense. Why do you have a `global` statement inside a `class`? Classes shouldn't contain code that has side effects.

Comment: Why have you defined `Get2` as a static method. Use `self` as the first argument in `Get2` and call it as `self.Get2` inside `main`.

Answer (score 1):

first of all, I'm leaving a note to look at how the global variable works in functions.

```
x = "awesome"

def myfunc():
  global x
  x = "fantastic"

myfunc()

print("Python is " + x)
```

The output of this code :
[image]

As you can see, the global variable is declared inside the function.
you can try to do it like this.

Comment: If you read the question carefully, the question was actually not about accessing a global variable, it was about accessing a method inside a class.